# Priorities of Pods in Google Container Cluster

Tags: google-app-engine, containers, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to schedule upcoming Pods/Containers based on their priorities?
(if container1 is critical and needs resources, the google orchestrator can kill other low priority containers)
If yes, is there some specific priorities tags (like: critical, monitoring, production...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This use case is described in both the [Borg paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43438.pdf) and the [Omega paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41684.pdf). However, it is not presently implemented within Kubernetes. Here are some related links to ongoing proposals:

- [QoS Tiers](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/147)
- [Preemption Policy / Scheme](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22212)
- [Resource Quality of Service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/resource-qos.md#under-development)